# How can I show a randomly selected welcome text from a google sheet column to web app index page?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to show a randomly selected text from Sheet1 column A1:A(last column with text) to the user. I can do it using google [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ljP5sKQDkMe8sX47pT7SPVNhyRe3o0fOPUVZ7pq9GNs/edit?usp=sharing) with

```
=index(A1:A50, randbetween(1, 50 ) )
```

[image]

and script code assigned to the Show button :

```js
function random1() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  var val = ss.getRange("B1").getValue()
  var clr = ss.getRange("C1").clearContent()
  ss.getRange("C1").setValue(val)
}
```

But I want to deploy it as a web app that will greet everyone with a different randomly selected text each time from the sheet. I think I need to make an HTML page but I don't know how can I show the string from variable val of code.gs to < div > at index page! How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

thoughts.gs:

```
function getThought() {
  var thoughtsA=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Thoughts").getDataRange().getValues();
  var index=Math.floor(Math.random()*(thoughtsA.length));
  return thoughtsA[index][0];
}

function launchThoughts() {
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('thoughts');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, "This Mornings Thought");
}
```

thoughts.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(thought) {
        $('#thought').html(thought);
      })
      .getThought();
    });
    </script>
  <style>#thought {font-size:60px;color:blue;}</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="thought"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My Spreadsheet has a sheet called "Thoughts".  It looks like this:

[image]

I presume you can add the thoughts.

Comment: Sorry! I'm getting "Script function not found: doGet" !!

Comment: Yes. Because I did it as a dialog. Look at `launchThoughts()` in thoughts.gs.  It's easy to change to a dialog but easier to debug as a dialog so get it working exactly and you wish and then convert it to a webapp.